# How to check if a node has a photo/video to use as an exposed filter in views?

Tags: views

I am interested in creating an exposed filter with the following values:

- Has photo
- Has video
- Has both photo and video

So this filter will check nodes and show only those with photos, if this filter is selected etc.

How can i do this? Should I create a new field on the content type and populate this according to having image/video?

Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add the photo field or fields as filters and set their criteria to "not empty". Then, only those records with a photo should be visible. The same applies for the video field.

Comment: Is this possible to combine the filter image and the filter video in single dropdown-exposed filter?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Do you mean to select it as an either or, so you can just check with a single field filter? I assume you can rewrite the value of a field to include the other field, then this may show up as a filter option, but I'm not really sure. You may need to experiment with this.